# ReactJS: Render html from imported data string inside .map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

New to ReactJS. I'm mapping over an array of data, some of which are strings with HTML tags. I'm trying to figure out how to render the html so that it's functional HTML. Currently it's outputted as a string in the browser.

Data:

```
const PROJECTS = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Website',
    dates: 'December 2015 - December 2017',
    description: 'Did some freelance work for <a href="www.website.com">website.com</a>.',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Website',
    dates: 'December 2015 - December 2017',
    description: 'Did some freelance work for <a href="www.website.com">website.com</a>.',
  }
];

export default PROJECTS;
```

React Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PROJECTS from '../data/projects';

class Projects extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      
          <div>
            {PROJECTS.map(PROJECT => {
              return(
                <article key={PROJECT.id}>
                  <h2>{PROJECT.title}</h2>
                  <p>{PROJECT.dates}</p>
                  <p>{PROJECT.description}</p>
                </article>
              )
            })}
          </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Projects;
```

Comment: I guess you are looking for https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Projects` so that the HTML is composed of JSX instead:

```
import React from 'react';
const PROJECTS = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Website',
    dates: 'December 2015 - December 2017',
    description: <>Did some freelance work for <a href="www.website.com">website.com</a>.</>,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Website',
    dates: 'December 2015 - December 2017',
    description: <>Did some freelance work for <a href="www.website.com">website.com</a>.</>,
  }
];
```

Them, `<p>{PROJECT.description}</p>` - which you already have - will render the JSX.

(You do need to import React, even though you're not creating a component - since this requires JSX, and JSX requires React.createElement, a React import is required)

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. These were all great answers, however I chose yours as I have control over this particular data file.

Answer (score 2):

There is a prop for visible html tag: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

Example:

```
const PROJECTS = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Website',
        dates: 'December 2015 - December 2017',
        description: 'Did some freelance work for <a href="www.website.com">website.com</a>.'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Website',
        dates: 'December 20' +
            '15 - December 2017',
        description: 'Did some freelance work for <a href="www.website.com">website.com</a>.'
    }
];


class Projects extends Component {
    render() {
        return (

            <div>
                {PROJECTS.map(PROJECT => {
                    return(
                        <article key={PROJECT.id}>
                            <h2>{PROJECT.title}</h2>
                            <p>{PROJECT.dates}</p>
                            <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html:PROJECT.description}}></p>
                        </article>
                    )
                })}
            </div>

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML. I've read about this before, but I often stumble over the correct implementation.

Answer (score 2):

An option is using the react-html-parser library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser which will avoid `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`. It also means you wouldn't need to manipulate your array if it was coming directly from an API, for example (but it's always good practice to sanitize it anyways).

The updated code would look like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PROJECTS from '../data/projects';
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser';

class Projects extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      
          <div>
            {PROJECTS.map(PROJECT => {
              return(
                <article key={PROJECT.id}>
                  <h2>{PROJECT.title}</h2>
                  <p>{PROJECT.dates}</p>
                  <p>{ReactHtmlParser(PROJECT.description)}</p>
                </article>
              )
            })}
          </div>

    )
  }
}

export default Projects;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Without using any third party library use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but you have to be sure you get valid html in the response everytime

return (
    <div>
        {PROJECTS.map(PROJECT => {
            return (
                <article key={PROJECT.id}>
                    <h2>{PROJECT.title}</h2>
                    <p>{PROJECT.dates}</p>
                    <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: PROJECT.description }}></p>
                </article>
            )
        })}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to use dangerouslySetInnerHTML. I've read about this before, but I often stumble over the correct implementation.